# Deploy an aws ecs service with 2 containers nginx and drupal in a single task defintion but still get error 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Here is my problem :

- I created an aws ecs task definition with 2 containers: nginx and drupal.

I choose awsvpc as the network mode.
The nginx container needs to communicate with the drupal container.

My nginx container listens on port 8080
My drupal container listens on port 9000

Here is the default.conf attached with the nginx container :

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

    root /app/src/web;

    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    include h5bp/internet_explorer/x-ua-compatible.conf;
    include h5bp/security/referrer-policy.conf;
    include h5bp/security/x-content-type-options.conf;
    include h5bp/security/x-xss-protection.conf;
    include h5bp/location/security_file_access.conf;
    include h5bp/cross-origin/requests.conf;

    port_in_redirect off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
}

# Block access to scripts in site files directory
location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
# location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

}
```

When I deployed this task definition inside my ecs cluster as a service with an alb as front-end I got an 503 error.

I read that "Multiple containers within a task in awsvpc networking mode will share the task ENI and the network namespace, so they can communicate to each other using localhost (or the equivalent 127.0.0.1 loopback IP address)".
So I keep the line realted to drupal as it is : fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so any advice will be welcome :)

Thanks,

Franck

Comment: You really need to look at the container logs. The Nginx log should tell you if it can't connect to the Drupal container. And the Drupal log should indicate if it is receiving any traffic or not. You also need to make sure your load balancer is showing healthy targets or not.

Comment: Also verify your target group is configured to send traffic to the nginx container, on port 8080.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B for your answer. There is no security group attached to a target group but I double-checked that the security group linked to the container instances allows traffic on port 8080. Apparently I don't have logs for nginx. I have to change that to see if I can find something.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, I posted  a comment. Also I didn't mention security groups (although  the security group for your target group is the security group assigned to the load balancer). What I mentioned was checking the port settings on your target group to verify it is actually forwarding traffic to port `8080` and to check if the target group is showing your instances as healthy or not.